# How to create lattice structure in Dot

Tags: graphviz, dot

I am trying to draw a diagram that will enumerate the list of all possible itemsets. It should look like this:

[image: Intended Output]

But I'm currently getting this:

[image: Resulting Output]

I tried to use the DOT language, but it didn't come out the same as the layout. My dot code is

```
digraph item_set {
// the first layer
A [label = "abcd=>{}"];

// the second layer
B1 [label = "bcd=>a"];
B2 [label = "acd=>b"];
B3 [label = "abd=>c"];
B4 [label = "abc=>d"];

// the third layer
C1 [label = "cd=>ab"];
C2 [label = "bd=>ac"];
C3 [label = "bc=>ad"];
C4 [label = "ad=>bc"];
C5 [label = "ac=>bd"];
C6 [label = "ab=>cd"];

// the forth layer
D1 [label = "d=>abc"];
D2 [label = "c=>abd"];
D3 [label = "b=>acd"];
D4 [label = "a=>bcd"];

// draw line between the first layer and the second layer
A -> {B1, B2, B3, B4} [dir = none];

// draw line between the second layer and the third layer
{B1, B2} -> C1 [dir = none];
{B1, B3} -> C2 [dir = none];
{B1, B4} -> C3 [dir = none];
{B2, B3} -> C4 [dir = none];
{B2, B4} -> C5 [dir = none];
{B3, B4} -> C6 [dir = none];

// draw line between the second layer and the third layer
{C1, C2, C4} -> D1 [dir = none];
{C1, C3, C5} -> D2 [dir = none];
{C2, C3, C6} -> D3 [dir = none];
{C4, C5, C6} -> D4 [dir = none]; }
```

Answer (score 0):

### Edges

The location at which the tail of an edge touches the start node can be controlled with `tailport`. The location where the head touches end node can be controlled with `headport`

```
digraph G {
  edge [dir=none]
  a -> b [color=red headport="n" tailport="s"]
  a -> c [headport="w" tailport="s"]
 }
```

[image: image showing use of headport and tailport]

### Fill

Adding the line:

```
 a [style=filled fillcolor="turquoise"]
```

before the closing brace fills node `a`.

[image: image showing node a with turquoise fill]

### Grouping Nodes with Subgraph

A group of nodes can be placed within a boundary using a named subgraph cluster. The boundary of the cluster can be styled. The complete code is:

```
digraph G {
  edge [dir=none]
  a -> b [color=red headport="n" tailport="s"]
  a -> c [headport="w" tailport="s"]
  subgraph cluster_0 {
      style="dashed"
      label="Low-Confidence\nRule"
      a [style=filled fillcolor="turquoise"]
  }  
}
```

[image: Image showing dashed boundary around group of nodes]

Comment: Thank you. I tried to modify my code, and I answer my question.

Answer (score 0):

Thank [ben rudgers](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2101909/ben-rudgers) for his direction. I modify my code, and now is

```
digraph item_set {

// set edge attribute
edge [dir = none tailport = "s" headport = "n"]
splines=false

// the first layer
A [label = "abcd=>{}"];

// the second layer
B1 [label = "bcd=>a"];
B2 [label = "acd=>b"];
B3 [label = "abd=>c"];
B4 [label = "abc=>d"];

// the third layer
C1 [label = "cd=>ab"];
C2 [label = "bd=>ac"];
C3 [label = "bc=>ad"];
C4 [label = "ad=>bc"];
C5 [label = "ac=>bd"];
C6 [label = "ab=>cd"];

// the forth layer
D1 [label = "d=>abc"];
D2 [label = "c=>abd"];
D3 [label = "b=>acd"];
D4 [label = "a=>bcd"];

// draw line between the first layer and the second layer
A -> {B1, B2, B3, B4} 

// draw line between the second layer and the third layer
{B1, B2} -> C1
{B1, B3} -> C2
{B1, B4} -> C3
{B2, B3} -> C4
{B2, B4} -> C5
{B3, B4} -> C6

// draw line between the second layer and the third layer
{C1, C2, C4} -> D1
{C1, C3, C5} -> D2
{C2, C3, C6} -> D3
{C4, C5, C6} -> D4

// subgraph
subgraph cluster_0 {
    style = "dashed"
    label = "Low-Confidence\n Rule"
    B1,C1,C2,C3,D1,D2,D3 [style = filled fillcolor = "grey"]
}
}
```

The output is
[image]

It works except for the layout.